# Version of C++ runtime on build machine vs customer machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vcredist

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution containing a C++ project. To be able to run the compiled application on customer machines I have included the latest C++ redistributable as a prerequisite in the installation program.

The C++ distributable that I included is the latest from Microsoft - version 11.0.61030.0.

When I search for msvcr110.dll on the build machine I see the file in multiple locations, but all files have the version 11.00.51106.1.

As I can see I have an older version on the build machine compared to the version I ship to the customers. Is this a problem? How do I update my build environment to the latest version?

Comment: You should better compile with /MT so the executable won't depend on any external runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building in external dependencies, then you should make certain that you have the same version installed on your build machine that you do on your customers machines. There can be bugs or inefficiencies that are corrected in latter versions, but even worse it's very possible that you could see side-by-side issues: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43681/Side-by-Side-Configuration-Incorrect

> Most of the developers using assemblies in their application may have faced this issue. While starting an application, we may get an error “This application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect”.

Anyway to get the latest redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 you can go here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: When I install the redistributable package on my build computer - do Visual Studio use the new version in the build?

Comment: @HenrikL Only if the Visual Studio on your build machine is up to date. That's what Side-by-Side does. Say that as the end user I'm running a program that was built with Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and another program that was built with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3. Side-by-Side lets both of those assemblies run in memory next to each other. That way for any given program I'm running with the assemblies that it was built with.